# why is there always 1 bye difference in html file size when I switch <meta charset="UTF-8"> to UTF-16

Tags: html, utf-8, character-encoding, filesize, utf

[utf-16](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGXSr.png)

[utf-8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aihj1.png)

why is it always one byte difference in file size(doesn't matter how many more characters I put it)? isn't supposed to have a larger difference that is proportional to # of characters?
(click the links to see my screenshots)

Comment: I suspect that the 1 byte difference is the extra digit when you write 16 instead of 8.  UTF-16 is variable encoding length which means that if you set the encoding as UTF-16 but don't use any characters that require more than a byte to represent, then the file size will remain the same as for UTF-8.

Comment: Did you also change the encoding of the file? Just changing the meta declaration to UTF-16 does not make it UTF-16 (same as renaming a .tar file to .zip does not make it a zip file)